# ManyToMany relations "trought" with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

with the following schema
[image: schema]

what is the proper way with Laravel 5 to get something like

```
    $table1Item->table2
```

but also can do something like

```
    $table1Item->table3->table1
```

so, what are the proper definition of relations ?

```
    class Table1 extends Model {
        public function table2() {
            return $this->...();
        }
        public function table3() {
            return $this->...();
        }
    }
    class Table2 extends Model {
        public function table1() {
            return $this->...();
        }
        public function table3() {
            return $this->...();
        }
    }
    class Table3 extends Model {
        public function table1() {
            return $this->...();
        }
        public function table2() {
            return $this->...();
        }
    }
```